# How to show the total quantity number(Like 10) instead of In Stock Status in Magento 2.x?

Tags: product, magento2.1.5, stock-status

I need help for Magento 2.x. Recently I have developed a eCommerce site. On products details page has "Stock Availability" using "In Stock" status.

So, I want to show the total number of quantity "like Stock: 20" instead of "In Stock" Status.

Could anyone please help to do that in my Magento 2.x eCommerce website.

Please check my attached images below then you can get the clear idea about my words what i have mentioned in above?

Please tell me where I have to write the code to get total quantity number Like "Stock: 20"
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Ben

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper class

```
namespace VendorName\StackExchange\Helper;


class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
     */
    protected $stockRegistry;

    /**
     * Data constructor.
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ) {
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getStockQty($product)
    {
        return $this->stockRegistry->getStockStatus($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->getQty();
    }
}
```

And now Overwrite following template
**Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml**

And add following code

```
<?php echo $this->helper('VendorName\StackExchange\Helper\Data')->getStockQty($_product);?>
```

Clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your helper or block to get product QTY.

`protected $stockItem;`

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockItem
) {
    $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getStockQty(ModelProduct $product)
{
    $qty = $this->stockItem->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    return $qty;
}
```

Inside Product View page

```
$helper = $this->helper('Namespace\Module\Helper\Data'); 
$qty = $helper->getStockQty($product); // Pass $product object
```

Hope it helps :)